# Why does differentiating $-\frac{2}{x+1}$ or $\frac{2x}{x+1}$ result in the same function $\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have some trouble understanding the **integration** of $\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$.

When integrated using $u$-substitution I get:

$$-\frac{2}{x+1}$$

However, I also know that:

$$\frac{2x}{x+1}$$

is a solution as well, due to the fact when you take the **derivative** of either one of the solutions mentioned above you end up with the same answer:

$$\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$$

I want to understand how the relation between the both integrated solutions **works** and **why**. I can't find any proof or examples that might guide me in the right way. Any help in understand this phenomena would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Observe that $$\frac{2x}{x+1}=2\frac x{x+1}=2\left(1-\frac1{x+1}\right)=2-\frac2{x+1}\ldots$$

Comment: As the answers show, the two functions differ only by a constant. Remember that when you do definite integration, you have to add on a constant of integration. So you could obtain answers $2x/(x+1)+C$ or $-2/(x+1)+D$ (where $C$ and $D$ can be anything). If $D=2+C$, the observations show you that you get the *same* function. Another way to say this is: the two functions differ by a constant, which is absorbed into the constant of integration.

Comment: I like to give as a similar example the facts that $\sin(x)^2$ and $-\frac1 2\cos(2x)$ both have derivative $2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(2x)$, and invite my students to explain how it can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that there should be a constant of integration, $C$, at the end of your answer that always differentiates to zero: $\int\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}\,dx=-\frac{2}{x+1}+C$. The integral of a function is not just one single function, but a whole family of infinitely many functions that differ only by a constant. And the second function is nothing more than the first function plus a $2$ (a constant):

$$
-\frac{2}{x+1}+2=
-\frac{2}{x+1}+2\frac{x+1}{x+1}=\\
\frac{-2}{x+1}+\frac{2x+2}{x+1}=
\frac{-2+2x+2}{x+1}=\\
\frac{2x}{x+1}.
$$

Since they're the same function, their derivatives should be equal:

$$
\left(-\frac{2}{x+1}+2\right)'=\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}+0=\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}.\\
\left(\frac{2x}{x+1}\right)'=\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}.
$$

Answer (score 8):

Because their difference is constant:$$\frac{2x}{x+1}-\frac{-2}{x+1}=\frac{2x+2}{x+1}=2.$$Therefore,$$\left(\frac{2x}{x+1}-\frac{-2}{x+1}\right)'=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$g(x)=\frac{-2}{1+x}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x}=2-\frac{2}{x+1}=Constant+g(x)$$